# Aruco Cube Pose Estiamtion

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, pose-estimation

I want to detect pose of the Cube (see image). I have the coordinates of centers of all markers and I want to draw axis on the origin/ or outline of the whole cube using 2D detection points and 3D object points. I am using opencv and I tried to draw the axis, on the image but detected axis are not correct.

[Aruco cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOrQ6.png)

I am using cv2.solvePnP, to get the rotation and translation vectors from detected 2D-3D point pairs.

[Detected axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03q1N.png)

for 3D object points Origin is at the one of the corners of the cube. The size of the cube is 20x20x20 cm.

Is it possible to do with opencv? Are there any other python libraries which could be useful to achieve the desired results?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

For people visiting this post recently, here is a solution I tried:

Cube Pose Tracking using OpenCV and ArUco Board in ROS

Overview
This ROS (Robot Operating System) node implements ArUco marker detection and pose estimation for a cube in a camera's field of view. It subscribes to camera information and image topics, performs marker detection using OpenCV's ArUco library, and estimates the pose of a cube with ArUco markers. The resulting pose information is published as a PoseStamped message and visualized using RViz markers.

Prerequisites ROS installed OpenCV installed (cv2, cv2.aruco) tf library installed numpy library installed

Usage Clone this repository into your ROS workspace.

https://github.com/ammar-n-abbas/aruco-cube-pose-tracking-ros.git

Build the ROS workspace.

cd path/to/your/ros/workspace catkin_make Run the ROS node.

rosrun your_package_name aruco_cube_pose.py

ROS Topics Subscribed Topics:

/camera/color/camera_info (CameraInfo): Camera information topic. /camera/color/image_raw (Image): Raw camera image topic. Published Topics:

/aruco_cube/pose (PoseStamped): Pose of the detected cube. /visualization_marker_real_cube (Marker): RViz visualization marker for the cube.

Parameters Marker Size: The size of the ArUco marker used for detection. Cube Size: The size of the cube.

Notes The node assumes a specific marker dictionary (DICT_6X6_1000). Please ensure that this matches your setup. Marker visualization in RViz is represented by a cube.

https://github.com/ammar-n-abbas/aruco-cube-pose-tracking-ros